# Python3 | classes | OOP

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, class, oop

```py
class Foo:
    """
    class to represent 2D arrays
    """
    def __init__(self, lst: list[list]) -> None:
        self.lst = lst

a_list = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 100]
]
```

If I want to access `10` in my variable `a_list`.
I type `a_list[2][1]`

What I am trying to do here is ...

I create an instance i.e `Foo(a_list)` and save it in a variable `n`.
So, `n = Foo(a_list)` is what I type.
Now, if I again want to access `10`. I surely can access it by `n.lst[2][1]`

My question here, is there anyway I can do the same thing the following way: `n[2][1]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) method. Something like

```py
class Foo:
    """
    class to represent 2D arrays
    """
    def __init__(self, lst: list[list]) -> None:
        self.lst = lst

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.lst[idx]
```

For your example, `n[2]` returns a list, so `n[2][1]` is indexing into a 'normal' python list.